# Running a Python script using Crontab

Tags: cron

I've written a python script which works well when I run it as `python3 /path/to/file/Script.py`, but once I try to run it through crontab it doesn't work as intended.
My script is supposed to download a file, parse it, append the data to a new text file and send the updated text file as an email.

I've tried using `crontab -e` and `sudo crontab -e`, but neither works. 
In both crontabs, I've tried:

```
45 20 * * * python3 /path/to/file/Script.py
45 20 * * * $(which python3) /path/to/file/Script.py
45 20 * * * /usr/bin/python3 /path/to/file/Script.py
45 20 * * * /path/to/file/Script.py (after adding #!/usr/bin/env python3 at the beginning of my script)
```

But none of these have worked. I changed the minutes and hours in the crontab format to time which can work and not in the past. I went into `/var/log/syslog` to see what went wrong, but to be completely honest, I don't understand what's going on.

The log file shows:

```
Mar 23 20:49:01 G3 CRON[10843]: (g3) CMD (/home/g3/covidfiles/COVID19.py)
Mar 23 20:49:01 G3 postfix/pickup[6415]: 435D914810F1: uid=1000 from=<g3>
Mar 23 20:49:01 G3 postfix/cleanup[8157]: 435D914810F1: message-id=<20200324004901.435D914810F1@G3>
Mar 23 20:49:01 G3 postfix/qmgr[6416]: 435D914810F1: from=<g3@G3>, size=593, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Mar 23 20:49:01 G3 postfix/pickup[6415]: 45822148041F: uid=0 from=<root>
Mar 23 20:49:01 G3 postfix/cleanup[6515]: 45822148041F: message-id=<20200324004901.45822148041F@G3>
Mar 23 20:49:01 G3 postfix/local[6519]: 435D914810F1: to=<g3@G3>, orig_to=<g3>, relay=local, delay=0.02, delays=0.01/0/0/0.01, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to mailbox)
Mar 23 20:49:01 G3 postfix/qmgr[6416]: 45822148041F: from=<root@G3>, size=625, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Mar 23 20:49:01 G3 postfix/qmgr[6416]: 435D914810F1: removed
Mar 23 20:49:01 G3 postfix/local[6520]: 45822148041F: to=<root@G3>, orig_to=<root>, relay=local, delay=0.03, delays=0.02/0/0/0.01, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to mailbox)
Mar 23 20:49:01 G3 postfix/qmgr[6416]: 45822148041F: removed
Mar 23 20:49:06 G3 postfix/pickup[6415]: C98061480A77: uid=1000 from=<g3>
Mar 23 20:49:06 G3 postfix/cleanup[8157]: C98061480A77: message-id=<20200324004906.C98061480A77@G3>
Mar 23 20:49:06 G3 postfix/qmgr[6416]: C98061480A77: from=<g3@G3>, size=924, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Mar 23 20:49:06 G3 postfix/local[6519]: C98061480A77: to=<g3@G3>, orig_to=<g3>, relay=local, delay=0.02, delays=0.01/0/0/0.01, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to mailbox)
Mar 23 20:49:06 G3 postfix/qmgr[6416]: C98061480A77: removed
```

It says that the emails were delivered to mailbox, but I haven't received anything and neither have the other recipients. I didn't have mailutils or postfix installed, so I installed them both. Neither of them solved my problems. This is a personal project, and I just don't know what path to take next. I want this script to be run once a day after 8:00pm EST.

I'm not sure if this helps, but I'm running Linux Mint Cinnamon and using Text Editor to write my code.

Comment: I just checked for both g3 and root and it's not there. The script isn't running altogether. It's not downloading the files from the url, parsing the data or appending it to my file. I believe it's an issue with either my operating system running crontab or crontab itself

Comment: I just realized `/var/mail` was supposed to be a directory, that's my bad. They both do exist!

Answer (score 0):

The `postfix` output from your `syslog` shows messages being delivered from `cron` to `g3` and to `root`. Depending on the mail subsystem you may find your emails in the directory /var/mail, either as the file `g3` or `root`, or failing that in subdirectories of `~/Maildir` in the respective home directories.

These mail files can be read properly with the `mail` (or `mailx`) command, but in this instance it's probably just as easy to use your favourite editor (`vi`) or pager (`less`) . They will contain messages from `cron` that may go some way to explaining *why* your script is failing to run.

If they do contain `cron` output but it's still not possible to see why your script is failing, modify your script to produce status messages as it goes (ideally writing to *stderr* rather than *stdout*), for example printing the value of key variables, etc.